# BUCARDO - PL/Perl function "validate_goat" at /usr/local/bin/bucardo

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-12, bucardo

I'm new to Bucardo, I have been trying to replicate PostgreSQL-12 using Bucardo with no success due to the errors.

```
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  DBI connect('dbname=test1','bucardo',...) failed:
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "bucardo" at line 64.
CONTEXT:  PL/Perl function "validate_goat" at /usr/local/bin/bucardo line 7292.
```

https://github.com/bucardo/bucardo/issues/133

https://github.com/bucardo/bucardo/issues/140

I have added full access to the postgres and bucardo users from both ~/.pgpass and pg_hba.conf

I have added every possible combination I know to the ~/.pgpass (in both postgres & bucardo home directories as mentioned)..

I was able to successfully add the database to bucardo. but not the Tables. I was able to do this by logging into the bucardo shell. (When logged into the postgres shell these commands failed)

```
bucardo add database pgmaster1 dbname=test1
bucardo add database pgmaster2 dbname=test1 host=pgmaster2
bucardo show all
```

The above commands work, but the following command does not work.

```
bucardo add all tables
```

I'm loosing my hair trying to find the correct combination to execute these commands.

I followed the https://bucardo.org/Bucardo/installation/
and https://bucardo.org/Bucardo/pgbench_example

And setup the bucardo, I also tried the https://bucardo-general.bucardo.narkive.com/roH4tJN4/authentication-problem-when-running-bucardo

I overcame the primary challenge with username& passwords (and finally found that pg_hba.conf trust every thing worked)

```
host    all     bucardo     ::1/128             trust
host    all     all         ::1/32              trust
host    all     postgres    192.168.1.192/32    trust
host    all     postgres    192.168.1.193/32    trust
host    all     bucardo     192.168.1.192/32    trust
host    all     bucardo     192.168.1.193/32    trust
```

The ~/.pgpass file (in both postgress and bucardo home)

```
192.168.1.192:5432:postgres:postgres:postgres
192.168.1.192:5432:bucardo:bucardo:bucardo
192.168.1.193:5432:postgres:postgres:postgres
192.168.1.193:5432:bucardo:bucardo:bucardo
```

Comment: `strace` the process and see where it looks for `.pgpass`.

Comment: From the error message it is clear you are using peer authentication here.  So pgpass can't matter, and your real in-use pg_hba can't list nothing but 'trust'.

Comment: @jjanes -I didn't quite get you. Can you provide a bit more information on your comment? Are you saying I need to change the authentication from 'trust' to 'md5' or something else?